# gnome shell extension website forgot username

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I forgot the username to my account on the gnome shell extension website. Although there is a way to reset passwords, there doesn't seem to be a way to see or reset usernames. Is there a method to do so?

Comment: I think you will find this follows usual convention as a privacy issue. Is there a reason not to reset your password and then use a password utility such as LastPass for the future?

Comment: @Graham I already have the password and email stored in a password manager. The issue is that I lost the username for my account and the site requires username to login. 

I currently have made another account using another email and It seems that changing username or email is not possible internally. Seems like poor design in my view.

Comment: Did you try resetting the password? Maybe your username is used somewhere in the email ("Dear [username]",...). Or maybe you are logged in after resetting the password and you can see it in your profile. Anyway, I agree that it's poorly designed.

Comment: @danzel ya. That was the first thing I tried, hoping that my username was sent along with instruction to reset the password. all the email I have gotten don't include the username